# Formik triggering errors and touched on non submit type button click. How can we only trigger when (type="submit") button clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

My Formik is triggering touched on all fields of form when non submit type button gets clicked. I already know If this is not a submit button, we can add `type="button"`. But since it's a third-party component so I cannot change it, How can formik trigger submit only when the actual `type="submit"` button clicked?

```
                    <Formik
                        initialValues={initialValues}
                        validationSchema={validationSchema}
                        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                            console.log("submit", { values, actions });
                          
                        }}

                        enableReinitialize={true}
                    >
                        {(props) => {
                            return (
                                <Form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
                                    <br />
                                <div class="row">
                            {/* Here this component contains buttons,I cannot add type="button" */}
                                  <SomethirdpartyLibWhichContainsButton />
                                </div>
                                    <div className="d-flex flex-row-reverse mx-3">
                                        <div >
                                            <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" >Submit</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>erros: {JSON.stringify(props.errors)} </p>
                                </Form>
                            )
                        }
                        }
                    </Formik>
```

Comment: can you provide a demo sandbox and which third party lib you are using?

Comment: @sathyareddy That is internal lib has no public access.

Comment: you need to specify type `button` in all your internal lib button, that should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Added prevent default in div, it worked!

```
const handler = event => {
  event.preventDefault()
}

<div class="row" onClick={handler}>
    {/* Here this component contains buttons,I cannot add type="button" */}
        <SomethirdpartyLibWhichContainsButton />
</div>
```